# c# ServiceStack Redis Clients grown up suddenly and get max number of clients reached

Tags: c#, redis, asp.net-core-6.0, servicestack.redis, redis-windows

im using redis with servicestack.

i get client with this code :

```
        public RedisClient GetClient()
        {
            RedisManagerPool redisManager = new RedisManagerPool();
            RedisClient client = (RedisClient)redisManager.GetClient();
            client.Db = AppConst.RedisServer;
            return client;
        }
```

everything go fine but suddenly my clients grown up and i get some errors and look like redis-server proccess down, make me restart server :

**max number of clients reached**

**Could not resolve master instance within 10000ms RetryTimeout**

and i set maxclient more value but still get this error but max number of.... replaced with **localhost:6379**

stacktrace :

at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResolver.CreateRedisClient(RedisEndpoint config, Boolean master) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisResolver.cs:line 110     at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisManagerPool.GetClient(Boolean forAsync) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisManagerPool.cs:line 222

at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.AssertConnectedSocket() in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisNativeClient_Utils.cs:line 292     at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.AssertServerVersionNumber() in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisNativeClient_Utils.cs:line 56     at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.GetServerRole() in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient.cs:line 1119     at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResolver.GetValidMaster(RedisClient client, RedisEndpoint config) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisResolver.cs:line 118     at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResolver.CreateRedisClient(RedisEndpoint config, Boolean master) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisResolver.cs:line 96

i search many times and i try some ways like set maxclients or maxpoolsize even UseIpRateLimiting and... but dont work.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `RedisManagerPool` incorrectly, all [Redis Client Managers](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis/client-managers#redis-client-managers) need to either be registered as a singleton or maintained in a static variable so all client instances are resolved from the same Pool.

If you're not using an IOC, maintain a static instance of `RedisManagerPool`, e.g:

```cs
static RedisManagerPool redisManager = new RedisManagerPool();

public RedisClient GetClient()
{
    RedisClient client = (RedisClient)redisManager.GetClient();
    client.Db = AppConst.RedisServer;
    return client;
}
```

Comment: thank u, i do changes and upload it,im waiting to see result,It happened before that there was no problem for a few days, but the error appeared again.
If I am sure that the problem is solved soon, I will put a green tick and you saved my life

Comment: :(( not work, its happend again

Comment: Make clients are always disposed after usage, e.g. whenever you can resolve it with: `using var redis = GetClient();`

Comment: i do this with using

Comment: See [troubleshooting](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis/troubleshooting) for avoiding common issues, e.g. I would add `RedisConfig.AssertAccessOnlyOnSameThread = true;` to ensure your clients are being properly disposed before being reused. If you still can't find the issue and can publish a standalone repro on GitHub I can take a look.

Comment: my problem not solved yet :(((((
when this problem happening i open redis-cli and info clients i get this error
"The disk is in use or locked by another process"
its hang, until i recycle app pool